# How to restrict auto RLT in react-native, react-native-i18n

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In my application when user change the language (to Arabic or some RTL supportive) of iPhone from settings, then the application layout changed automatically to RTL. I have used the **react-native-i18n**. Can you please describe how can i restrict this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**import "I18nManager" from react-native and set allowRTL to false**

**Try this**

```
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';

...

I18nManager.allowRTL(false)
```